# help needed with doctype

Tags: html, css, doctype

I'm having trouble with a test site's design. When I'm opening my html page with IE, without my doctype line, it renders just the way I like it, but not in FF (because of the way it interprets padding, among other things). When I add the doctype line, the page gets squeezed to a height of about 230px. My intention is to set the height to the maximum page height.
Here are my files:

*** index.html ***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="stylesheet.css" /> 
   <!--[if IE]>
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    text-align: center;
    /* Remove padding: */
    padding: 0;
   }
   #container {
    /* Mind the box model in IE.. */
    height: 100%;
   }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
</head>  
<body>
<!--[if IE]><div id="container"><![endif]-->
<div class="container">
     <div class="header">  
         <h1>Logo</h1>  
     </div>
     <div class="nav widget-header ">
            <!-- main nav -->
            <a href=""><div class="nav-button state-default " ><img src="a.jpg" alt="a" /></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="nav-button state-default " ><img src="b.jpg" alt="b" /></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="nav-button state-default " ><img src="c.jpg" alt="c" /></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="nav-button state-default " ><img src="d.jpg" alt="d" /></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="nav-button state-default " ><img src="e.jpg" alt="e" /></div></a>
    </div >
    <div class="content">
        <!--content area-->
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <!-- footer -->
        <p>&copy; Copyright</p>
     </div>
</div>
<!--[if IE]></div><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

*** stylesheet.css ***

```
/* reset */
html, body, div, span,   
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,  
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,  
img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,  
sbutton_cl, strike, strong,   
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,  
fieldset, form, label, legend,  
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {  
    margin: 0;  
   padding: 0;  
   border: 0;  
   outline: 0;  
   font-size: 100%;
}  
.body{
    line-height: 1;  
    text-align: center;
}

.widget-header {
background:#333333 url(images/bg-state-default.png) repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;;
border:1px solid #333333;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-weight:bold;
}

.state-default {
    background: #CC0000 url(images/button-state-default.png) repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
    border:1px solid #333333;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    outline-color:-moz-use-text-color;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:medium;
}

.container  {

    border: 1px solid #999999;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#999999;
}

.header  {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height:10%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height:10%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-button {

    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
}

.content{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height:60%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

.footer{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height:10%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is a design with fixed width and percentage-based height, where child divs are also percentage-based positioned to their parents ( I believe this is the correct way to deal with different screen resolutions ).

I'll be very grateful if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: You might have more luck with this on doctype

Comment: One hint, in your nav, block elements (like <div>) shouldn't be inside inline elements (like <a>). What you could do is add the CSS rule display:block; to .nav-button and apply the classes to the link, not a div inside the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I appreciate his effort, meder's answer was helpful, but incomplete since i want to have a percentage-based design. Dave's answer is more like guidelines. The best solution to my problem is something similar to this: 
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Now my problem is solved, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#wrapper { background:red; }
html,body{height:100%;}
#wrapper{min-height:100%;}
</style>
<!--[if IE 6]><style>
#wrapper { height:100%; }
</style><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id=wrapper>
  <p>Hello from JS Bin</p>

  <p id="hello"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get rid of the IF IE conditional for the HTML and use id=container.

Comment: Try now - I updated the source and here's a live demo: http://jsbin.com/owohe
Did not test in IE though.

Comment: Thank you. This makes the container take the full height of the page. However, the nested divs still get squeezed; it appears that they ignore any percentage i give them: .nav{ min-height:10% } or .nav{ min-height:100% } aren't making any difference, while .nav{ min-height:100px } does. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't really be doing this as it's not flexible and very, very unorthodox in terms of layout. I suggest you not give specific percentages. 

Though since the wrapper is now 100% of the body, html all the direct children will need heights, not min-height. It would also help actually seeing a visual example.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear which version of Explorer you're using (apart from 6), but `min-height` is read as `height` by some versions...

However - this is the professional (and easiest way) way to build HTML/CSS:

1. validate your HTML (important, as invalid HTML can confuse browsers in unpredictable ways!)
2. get it working and looking how you like in FF;
3. add conditional comments for IE6 and (if necessary) IE7 and 8.

In IE 6 remember that padding etc. is *not added* to a box, so will decrease any width or height. Also, some elements without certain CSS properties, e.g. no specific width or height (or `auto`), do not [trigger 'haslayout' in IE](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

That may not have solved the problem directly, but I hope it helps pin things down!